# How to reduce the filesize of an image without altering its dimensions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, file-size, compression

I have a `5760px x 3840px` image with a filesize of`1.14MB`.
I would like to reduce its filesize to `200KB` without altering its dimensions.

How can I do this in Photoshop?

Comment: try `File...` > `Save for Web...` and fiddle with the *.jpg settings.

Comment: as @Bakabaka says above, just mess with the optimization settings and look in the bottom left for the updated file size.  Although that seems to be an extremely large image to be taking down under a quarter of a meg.  The quality is going to be horrific.

Comment: You are not going to get a 1000% reduction in file size and retain quality, it's just not going to happen.

Comment: To add on Scott's comment, you have to compromise something with that level of reduction. Generally you need either a lot less colors (go to 8-bit for example), smaller dimensions or heavy compression (artifacts). In your case, you might need all of them together.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved by using the function "File>Save for Web..."

[image: SaveForWeb1]

In the upper right corner you can select a preset and the file type. If you select JPEG and go with the settings in the picture above, you will get a small resolution picture with the same dimensions. You can play around with the settings and in the bottom left corner you can see the current size of the image. (My picture is now 4.669KB)

Hope this method will also help you in the future because you can do this for any image type by just selecting a different one in the upper right corner!

Answer (score 1):

If you're saving the image as a JPEG you could lower the quality setting until you get your optimal file size.

[image]

This can significantly affect the visual quality of your image though so it all depends how you want your final image to look.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try which hasn't been mentioned is in the **Save For Web** dialog, if you click the **Menu** in the upper right corner you can choose `Optimize for File Size...`

[image]

You and then input your desired file size and Photoshop will do it's best to get there. Be prepared though. A 1000% reduction in file size is going to result in an image of absolutely horrible quality.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not possible, especially for a non-uniform color field (e.g. a photograph).

In terms of raw image size without compression, you are dealing with a minimum of 5760 x 3840 **bits**. `(((5760*3840)/8)/1024)/1024` is 2.6MB. Photoshop's "New" dialog confirms this.

An RGB image of this size, filled with uniform noise and saved as jpeg with "worst possible quality" compression is 16MB.

Comment: Although I like calculation based answers, I don't think it's the right place here. The OP seems to be a beginner and this information will probably be confusing. According to your explanation a 1.14MB image with these dimensions (the one OP has now) would not be possible.

Comment: With the information given by the OP, we are left to wonder what the image content and the image file type are. I will add, though, that "uniform noise" in my answer is probably going to be the worst-case for most compression. A 100% white fill is over 200k at maximum jpeg compression. There are probably other compression methods more suitable for 100% fill. In any case, the OP need not accept my answer but the details might be useful for others.

Answer (score -2):

This is not your requirement. But, I suggest you use [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com) tool. Just drag and drop and let's tool compress your image.